# jquery ui autocomplete.Задний фон элемента при наведении

Tags: javascript, jquery, ui

Привет. Проблемка с  jquery ui autocomplete.
[image]
как видно на картинке я сделал задний фон для `<li>` при наведении мышки но тут еще вокруг текста фон.Так вот не пойму как его убрать.
Из инспектора в хроме я нашел класс который вешается на div в котором текст.
Но задав этому класс стиль

```
.ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover {
    background-color:none;
    border:none;
}
```

не чего не изменилось.Кто нить знает как убрать задний фон.

2 ВОПРОС
добавил к autocomplete

```
focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-menu-item").css({ 'backgroundColor': 'black' });
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
```

но он заливает все элементы а не тот что в фокусе

Comment: Если вы сами решили задачу, может быть, опубликуете ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найти класс добавляемый списку в родном css файле и править там.Почему то изменения вносились только там.